# How to link SharePoint list to a map? (Link a map to a SharePoint list)

Tags: sharepoint, google-maps, maps, linked-list

I want to link a SharePoint list to a map to color code regions, based on criteria from the list. Can someone help, or suggest an easy to build solution?

Thanks,

Comment: There isn't an easy solution for that, you might try the Bing Maps API, or the ESRI Maps API to see if either will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at either custom development as suggest above, or look at contributing/re-using  the following codeplex project http://googlemapswebpart.codeplex.com/